# going from http to https version of site in firefox has insecure elements on first load

Tags: https

Our e-commerce site uses http for general site browsing to https for checkout.  This process works in all browsers except for firefox.  On firefox, we are seeing a an error that not all elements are secure.

Using forefox:

1. Go to http://www.creativecrash.com/marketplace/3d-models/vehicle/cars/sedan/c/seat-ibiza-2013-5door
2. click Add to Cart
3. click Checkout

Now the site should not be partially secure.  If you click the icon beside the URL it should say "Your connection to this site is only partially encrypted, and does not prevent eavesdropping".

Now reload the page. It should suddenly be fully secure.

Any ideas on why this is happening and how we can fix it would be most appreciated.

Comment: As I can see you have solved your problem. Can you tell how did you do it? I have a similar problem using firefox and haven't found a solution yet.